# How many non-empty subsets are there of the set $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$? Give your answer in closed form.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I have been thinking about this question for a while and the subsets of $\{1, \ldots,n\}$ with even sum are one-to-one with the subsets of $\{2, \ldots,n\}$ and those with an odd sum would result in $\{1, \ldots,n-1\}$...

I think I am on the right track but how do I write my answer in closed form?

Comment: How many non-empty subsets are there of $\{1,2\}$ and $\{1,2,3\}$?

Answer (score 0):

There is only one empty subset, and all the rest of them, $2^n-1$ in total, are non-empty.

Comment: There are $2^n$ subsets of an $n$-element sets.  The ones which are non-empty, are therefore $2^n-1$, the number of subsets excluding the empty set.  Why do you think the OP knows that any n element set has $2^n$ subsets?  See the accepted answer at the duplicated post.